# What's confusing about this sentence?

Tags: syntax, verbs

Consider the following sentence:

> Clean up the design database to initialize costing.

I find the sentence to be confusing but I'm a native English speaker. I asked my wife about it and she responded that *“costing is a present participle”* and *“it's being nominalized (made into a noun), but we're not used to that”.*

The author responded with:

> "Now costing in pure grammatical sense in this case would be a noun formed from a verb. Something which american english term as verbal noun. (or like your wife mentioned is similar to a present participle). So probably grammatically this is correct"

Which is correct?

Comment: The sentence is confusing because it's jargon. _Initialize_ has a large number of meanings, and so do _costing_, _clean up_, and _design_. _Database_, hopefully, is not metaphoric, but the rest are. They use a number of incommensurable metaphor themes, and it's simply not clear what's being asked. Moral: most of the time, when something is unclear, it's not a grammar problem.

Comment: This sentence is very confusing, but so are a lot of IT-related tasks.  The industry is unfortunately laden with buzzwords and jargon.   Microsoft defines "File Costing" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368593(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: maybe it's confusing because it's syntactically ambiguous? i.e., *clean up [the design database to initialize costing]* vs. *clean up the design database [to initialize costing]*

Comment: @jlovegren That is possible but humans tend to be pretty good at resolving those ambiguities without ever noticing them. I didn't even realize it was ambiguous until you pointed it out. Reading balor123's question I get the impression they feel the sentence is somehow "incorrect", which makes me think it's a jargon issue.

Comment: Expanding on @jlawler 's comment: I think your problem is that you have a hard time separating syntax (grammar) from semantics (meaning). The classic example is "Colourless green ideas sleep furiously". The sentence structure "adj adj n v abv" is grammatical but the problem is that there are logical inconsistencies: colourless things cannot be green; ideas cannot have colour; ideas cannot sleep; one cannot sleep "furiously". In this case, the sentence is using words with a domain-specific meanings (jargon) that you might not know and thus might mistake as being logically inconsistent.

Comment: I'm not so sure "costing" is the verb "cost" nominalized. If my guess is correct "costing" is jargon for calculating some kind of cost. Can you use it as a verb in this sense? Can "Let's cost" mean "Let's calculate costs"?

Comment: @Dainich: yes, you can use the verb in this sense, but only with an object: "Let's cost this project" is fine. You're right that "costing" has a meaning beyond the verbal noun: it is also used to mean the result of applying the verb: the cost itself. So "let's look at those costings" would mean "let's look at the lists of costs somebody has worked out".

Comment: interesting...i find it confusing too. do u have the context ? taken out of context seems unclear , try posting the whole sentence or paragraph or what u feel may help us understand it . greetings !!!

Comment: It was a single line comment from a piece of code to describe a function. Why aren't all these comments answers? I'd love to give one of these great answers credit :)

Comment: Try the English learners and teachers stackexchange for this question, http://ell.stackexchange.com